# Connecting function to empty cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to use the following info from Google deployment manager examples on GitHub.

[empty_bucket_in_function.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/google/resource-snippets/cloudfunctions-v1/empty_bucket_in_function.yaml)

**empty_bucket_cf.yaml**

```
imports:
- path: empty_bucket_cf.jinja

resources:
- name: my-function
  type: empty_bucket_cf.jinja
  properties:
     project: <PROJECT_NAME>
     region: europe-west1
     entryPoint: handler
     runtime: nodejs8
     bucket: lskflsjfsj
```

**empty_bucket_cf.jinja**

```
{% set BUCKET = properties['bucket'] + '-bucket' %} resources:
#- type: cloudfunctions.v1.function
- type: gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions   name: my-function   properties:
    parent: projects/{{ properties['project'] }}/locations/{{ properties['region'] }}
    location: {{ properties['region'] }}
    function: my-{{ properties['bucket'] }}
    sourceArchiveUrl: gs://$(ref.{{ BUCKET }}.name)/my-function
    entryPoint: {{ properties['entryPoint'] }}
    runtime: {{ properties['runtime'] }}
    eventTrigger:
      resource: $(ref.my-topic.name)
      eventType: providers/cloud.pubsub/eventTypes/topic.publish
#- type: pubsub.v1.topic
- type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics   name: my-topic   properties:
    topic: {{ properties['bucket'] }}-topic
#- type: storage.v1.bucket
- type: gcp-types/storage-v1:buckets   name: {{ BUCKET }}   properties:
    predefinedAcl: projectPrivate
    projection: full
    location: US
    storageClass: STANDARD
```

While deploying using deployment manager I am getting error as

```
testsetup has resource warnings
my-function: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v1:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":"Failed to retrieve function source code"}
Deployment properties
```

Any idea why this is not a bug in Google Cloud Platform GitHub repository. Isn't it the purpose of empty_bucket config to create CFs with empty bucket.

**Note: Sometimes it executes successfully as well.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't what Google had in mind when they publish this example, but it can't work. If your bucket is empty, the function has no code. However, when you deploy a function, the code is compiled/parsed, the entry-point checked (exists, correct signature,...), and deployed on the environment.

Here, no entry point, no code to compile/parse thus no deployment -> It's normal, but the example is disturbing. You can open an issue on the repos.

Comment: the weird part is that it finishes successfully sometimes and sometimes it fails. I have added a screenshot which says it finished successfully.